# Programmatically center icons in a TabBarItem in a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm programmatically generating a UITabBarController (instantiating view controllers and assigning them to my UITabBarController's viewControllers array).  I don't want titles for my TabBarItems.  However, the TabBarItems by default make space for a title, so my icon images are centered 5 pixels higher than they should be.  Is there a programmatic way to "center" i.e. shift or give offsets to the TabBarItem's image?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the imageInsets property to move the frame of the icon.

Comment: It is not a critique or a request for clarification. It is a statement on how to achieve what the OP wanted to do, i.e. an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this (and even if you managed to cheat and find a way to shift this stuff down it would no doubt be denied by Apple during the approval process).